# Getting "Unexpected token" error while configure eclipse protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, eclipse, protractor

I'm trying to execute my protractor files using eclipse. I have done the below steps:

```
 1, From Eclipse marketplace installed "AngularJS Eclipse1.2.0 & Tern Eclipse IDE1.2.0"
 2, Created new "Java script" project
 3, converted created project into "Tern Project"
 4, Placed the protractor spec.js & conf.js
 5, installed protractor locally. I can able to see the mode_modules
 6, Launched Run Config and set the "config_file", "working directory", "protractor cli.js"
```

After the above configuration I tried to execute the conf.js file but got the below error:

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The error tells you that the runtime environment you are running the logger.js in cannot recognise spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting in `info(...msgs)` is using ES6 syntax called Spread operator. You can go through this link for more about it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator 
Might be your npm version is less than you are running. Upgrade to latest version might resolve the problem.